# Alphabetical order does not work properly after adding a new factor in the dataframe to replace another

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
AS<-c("Composite", "DGIdb", "DrugBank", "DrugCentral_Human",
      "Repurposing", "LINCS_Data_Portal","TargetCentral")
ASe<-c("Composite", "DGIdb", "DrugBank", "DrugCentral (Human)",
       "Drug Repurposing Hub", "LINCS Data Portal","TargetCentral")
d<-data.frame(AS,ASe)
```

and I replace the "Repurposing" of the `AS` column with "Drug Repurposing Hub" with:

```
levels(d$AS) <- c(levels(d$AS),"Drug Repurposing Hub") 
d$AS[d$AS=="Repurposing"] <- "Drug Repurposing Hub"
```

But when I try to order the data frame alphabetically based on the `AS` column

```
d<-data.frame(d[order(d$AS),])
```

I get:

```
                    AS                  ASe
1            Composite            Composite
2                DGIdb                DGIdb
3             DrugBank             DrugBank
4    DrugCentral_Human  DrugCentral (Human)
6    LINCS_Data_Portal    LINCS Data Portal
7        TargetCentral        TargetCentral
5 Drug Repurposing Hub Drug Repurposing Hub
```

while the "Drug Responsing Hub" should have been in the 5th row.

Comment: You're asking to order d$AS by the order of its levels, and with `levels(d$AS) <- c(levels(d$AS),"Drug Repurposing Hub") ` you defined "Drug Repurposing Hub" as the last level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For levels: It seems to me to be OK here. But, in case you do not get it to elucidate this, I suggest using the forcats package

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
AS<-c("Composite", "DGIdb", "DrugBank", "DrugCentral_Human",
      "Repurposing", "LINCS_Data_Portal","TargetCentral")
ASe<-c("Composite", "DGIdb", "DrugBank", "DrugCentral (Human)",
       "Drug Repurposing Hub", "LINCS Data Portal","TargetCentral")
d<-data.frame(AS,ASe)
levels(d$AS) <- c(levels(d$AS),"Drug Repurposing Hub") 
d$AS[d$AS=="Repurposing"] <- "Drug Repurposing Hub"
d
```

```
> d
                    AS                  ASe
1            Composite            Composite
2                DGIdb                DGIdb
3             DrugBank             DrugBank
4    DrugCentral_Human  DrugCentral (Human)
5 Drug Repurposing Hub Drug Repurposing Hub
6    LINCS_Data_Portal    LINCS Data Portal
7        TargetCentral        TargetCentral
```

```
df <- d %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(AS = forcats::fct_relevel(AS, sort),
                ASe = forcats::fct_relevel(ASe, sort))
df
```

```
> df
                    AS                  ASe
1            Composite            Composite
2                DGIdb                DGIdb
3             DrugBank             DrugBank
4    DrugCentral_Human  DrugCentral (Human)
5 Drug Repurposing Hub Drug Repurposing Hub
6    LINCS_Data_Portal    LINCS Data Portal
7        TargetCentral        TargetCentral
```

Also to organize.

```
dfx <- d %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(AS = forcats::fct_relevel(AS, sort),
                ASe = forcats::fct_relevel(ASe, sort)) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(AS, ASe) #
```

Comment: What if I have a lot more than two columns -unlike AS,ASe- here?

Comment: make a loop with `for`.

Comment: Im stuck in using the loop

Comment: Ask another question, provide a reproducible example, make it clear that you have many columns in your data frame. Surely someone will help you set up a function or loop.